# DllImport in reference of loaded native DLL

Tags: c#

I am using a third party dll built with VS2008 that relies on `msvcr90.dll` for printing to `stdout`. I try to redirect this output with `SetStdHandle`, but the dll seems to miss a final call to flush the output buffer before returning.

Simply using

```
[DllImport("msvcr90.dll")]
```

leads to a DllNotFoundException.

To solve the problem, I PInvoke `fflush()` and `__iob_func()` from `msvcr90.dll` which resides in my WinSxS folder. I did this by setting the full path to the dll (I got the path using DependencyWalker on the third party dll). What is of course not very usefull if I want to give my program to other people or if `msvcr90.dll` is updated by Microsoft.

Can anybody give me a hint, how to tell DllImport to use the recent version of `msvcr90.dll`?

Thanks for any reply!

Andreas

**My Solution**

With Davids help I came up with the following solution. `msvcr90.dll` is not located through WinSxS, but taken from the loaded module list.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace siemens.OptiX
{
    static unsafe class FlushPrintBuffer
    {
        struct CFile
        {
            char* _ptr;
            int _cnt;
            char* _base;
            int _flag;
            public int _file;
            int _charbuf;
            int _bufsiz;
            char* _tmpfname;
        }

        [DllImport("kernel32", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true)]
        static extern IntPtr GetProcAddress(IntPtr hModule, string procName);

        [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        private delegate CFile* iobFuncDelegate();

        [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        private delegate int flushDelegate(CFile* stream);

        static iobFuncDelegate myIobFunc;
        static flushDelegate myFlush;

        static FlushPrintBuffer()
        {
            ProcessModuleCollection allLoadedModules = 
                Process.GetCurrentProcess().Modules;

            IntPtr aDllHandle = allLoadedModules
                .Cast<ProcessModule>()
                .Where(p => string.Compare(p.ModuleName, "msvcr90.dll", true) == 0)
                .First()
                .BaseAddress;

            IntPtr aIobFuncPtr = GetProcAddress(aDllHandle, "__iob_func");
            myIobFunc = Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(
                aIobFuncPtr, typeof(iobFuncDelegate)) as iobFuncDelegate;

            IntPtr aFlushPtr = GetProcAddress(aDllHandle, "fflush");
            myFlush = Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(
                aFlushPtr, typeof(flushDelegate)) as flushDelegate;
        }

        static public void flushNow()
        {
            CFile* aFilePtr = myIobFunc();
            int aRes = myFlush(&(aFilePtr[1]));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not particularly clear why you need to P/Invoke the function from a *specific* version of the runtime. Is your code really dependent upon the implementation found in version 9 of the CRT? (And if so, have you considered that might be a problem?)

Comment: File handles to stdout are specific for every copy of the CRT dll. [Have a look at](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235460.aspx). So if I want to flush the right buffer, I have to use the same copy of the dll as my third party tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you will find it hard to use `DLLImport` to link to the right runtime. This is because your executable will be missing the necessary manifest to make the WinSxS magic work.

I would declare some delegates for the functions you need to import. Use `GetProcAddress` to obtain the function pointers. You convert the function pointers into delegates with [`Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getdelegateforfunctionpointer.aspx).

In order to get the module handle to pass to `GetProcAddress` you can use `GetModuleHandle(@"msvcr90.dll")` since you know that this is loaded into your process.

Get hold of `GetProcAddress` and `GetModuleHandle` with P/invoke.

---

It seems calling `GetModuleHandle(@"msvcr90.dll")` will not work.  Calling `GetModuleHandle` with the full path would work, but that's not really a tenable solution.

Instead it is easy enough to enumerate the loaded modules like this:

```
IntPtr MyGetModuleHandleByPartialName(string ModuleName)
{
    foreach (ProcessModule module in Process.GetCurrentProcess().Modules)
        if (module.FileName.ToLower().Contains(ModuleName))
            return module.BaseAddress;
    return IntPtr.Zero;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your hint David! I tried it out, but although ProcessExplorer shows me, that the dll is loaded, GetModuleHandle only returns 0. Can you give me another tip, please?

Comment: It should work I think. Are you sure that you have loaded your DLL before calling `GetModuleHandle`?

Comment: Yes, I initialized the third party library before the GetModuleHandle call and steped through the region with the debugger. After the initialization msvcr90.dll appears in ProcessExplorer's dll list.

Comment: So I had another idea. Using System.Diagnostic.Process, I can get all loaded modules by name and so can achieve the dll's full path. Caling GetModuleHandle on the full path gives me a valid pointer. I will try to do the next steps now ...

Comment: @Andreas We came up with the same idea at the same time! See the edit. Anyway, you don't need to call `GetModuleHandle` on the full path, just read the module handle out of the `BaseAddress` property, they are the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Just out of interest you have installed the Visual C++ Runtime using the installer?  You're saying that the DLL is present and installed correctly and dllimport is failing?

Have a read [here](http://omnicognate.wordpress.com/2009/10/05/winsxs/) for more info:

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, I installed runtime using the installer. And when I give the full path, the import works. Now I will have a look on the promissing blog entry!